# Can't enable AzPredictor

Tags: windows, powershell

Enable-AzPredictor: The 'Enable-AzPredictor' command was found in the module 'Az.Tools.Predictor', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Tools.Predictor'.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Well... Did you run `Import-Module Az.Tools.Predictor` first?

Comment: Yeah. I did this. I found the issue. The Az.Accounts module had not been installed properly. Now it is working well after installing Az.Accounts Module. Thank you my friend for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that might be having this issue, there are two externally managed, dependent modules for Az.Tools.Predictor :

1.Az.Accounts

2.PSReadLine

Also, i believe Az.Tools.Predictor requires Powershell 7.2 (minimum version) to run.

Check that you have these updated and that you are using Powershell Core.

If you need to uninstall and install it again you try these steps:

#open cmd as admin and open pwsh with no profile:

```
pwsh -noprofile
```

#uninstall any previous installations of Az.Tools.Predictor

```
Uninstall-Module -Name Az.Tools.Predictor -Force
```

#install latest version of PSReadline:

```
Install-Module -Name PSReadline -Force
```

#install Az.Tools.Predictor

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Tools.Predictor -verbose
```

*verbose here, will let you know where the module was installed.

#open new powershell core window

```
Enable-AzPredictor -AllSession
```

Hope this helps.